# How to manage transaction across micro services using 2 phase commit protocol?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, xa, atomikos

I have two micro services. One is in spring boot and other is using simple jdbc apis to perform database operation. I have to perform database operation using these two services. 
(i.e.

1. Insert using jdbc service,
2. Insert using spring-boot service,
3. Insert using jdbc service).

These operation should follow acid property.

I have tried saga pattern using axon framework, it is working fine but I want to do it by using 2pc protocol. I have tried 2pc protocol in jdbc service but it is working only for transactions happened only in this service. I also used atomikos framework in spring service, it is working for this service only.
 Is there any way to co-ordinate javax.transaction and springframework.transaction ?

Comment: Don't. Distributed commits are notoriously difficult to implement. If you are looking for atomic behaviour across micro-services, then maybe your boundaries haven't been defined properly.

Comment: @PrashantPandey , can you please suggest is there any way to implement atomic behavior across micro-services prefer 2pc protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario described in the question, you should try using Oracle Transaction Manager for Microservices (MicroTx). It is a free product that comes with a transaction manager and client library for microservices written in Java and node.js. With this, you can create XA (2PC) transactions involving multiple microservices. Oracle MicroTx - https://www.oracle.com/database/transaction-manager-for-microservices